# Making a Content Template Apply to Only Select TabItems in TabControl, WPF

Tags: wpf, templates, tabcontrol

I am trying to create dynamic tabs that open and close like in web browsers. However, I am trying to make it such that there is one unchangeable, unclosable tab (like a control tab), which can open up multiple other closable tabs. This tab would be initialized from the start. The unclosable tab has a different format than the closable tabs. I want to write two content templates: one that applies to the control tab, and one that applies to all the closable tabs. Is it possible to have two different content templates for the same TabControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is to provide templates to the individual `TabItems` not the entire `TabControl`. For example in XAML:

```
   <TabControl>
        <TabItem Template="MyControlTabTemplate" Header="Control Tab"  />
        <TabItem Template="MyOtherTabTemplate" Header="Other Tab" />
   </TabControl>
```

You can create more `TabItems` as you wish in the code-behind.

Comment: Thanks, but two things:

(1) I don't have an explicit TabItem. I have a DataTemplate instead. Will this still work?
(2) How do you define the templates? In your example, what is the format for writing up "MyControlTabTemplate" and "MyOtherTabTemplate"?

Comment: I would move towards using `TabItems` If you're using a tab control. In terms of writing the templates you can get started here [MSDN TabItem Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752032(v=vs.85).aspx). But more research on templates in general may be required on your part.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to do it. Thanks for your help!
The general idea is to create multiple DataTemplates under TabControl.Resources, to name the DataTemplates properly, and to set the ContentTemplate property of new TabItems in the CodeBehind to the key corresponding to the appropriate DataTemplate. It seems you can do this with Data Templates, and other UIFramework items as well.